# How do I add a java program to a weebly site?

Tags: java, swing, weebly

I'm experimenting with Weebly, and I'm currently trying to add an arbitrary swing program to the Weebly editor. I have tried two approaches thus far, as shown here:

1: (Note: - replaces < and >)

```
-embed height=400 width=400 src="siteName/uploads/someNumbers/testapplet.class"--/embed-
```

2: (Same substitution as above)

```
-applet codebase="siteName/uploads/someNumbers" code="testapplet.ckass" width=400 height=400--/applet-
```

Upon publishing and viewing the page, the first one says I need a plugin to display the content, and the second one says my security preferences won't let me run java on the site, whereas I can run java pretty much everywhere else just fine.

What should I do to make this work? This could include some of the following:

1. Modifying my program (i.e. the java code itself)
2. Modifying how I upload the program (i.e. .class vs .jar)
3. Modifying how I display the program (i.e. the actual -applet- or -embed-)

For reference, here is the java code- just a basic JButton and JLabel, with the JLabel's value increasing upon each click of the button:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class TestApplet extends JApplet
{
   static int x = 0;
   static JLabel l = new JLabel(x+"");
   public void init()
   {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      JButton b = new JButton("Button");
      b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x++;
            l.setText(x+"");
         }
      });
      add(b);
      add(l);
   }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 3) The best way to deploy a Java **desktop application** is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I want to make my Java program available to my colleagues, while reducing the amount of work they and I have to do. Are you saying that Java Web Start is a solution that I can implement in a relatively short period of time, and that would be easy for others to use?

Comment: Define 'easy'. Browsers used to hand the launch file directly to the JWS launcher, but now will typically download it instead, then the user has to open it explicitly. There is no 'one click to launch' ability for Java apps. anymore, because Sun/Oracle kept stuffing up security.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign in to weebly and click on the edit button next to your site name
2. On the "Elements" tab on the top, go to "Multimedia" and drag a file element onto your page.
3. Follow directions to upload your .class file.  Name should be lowercase.
4. Hit the publish button and go to your published page.
5. Remember your .class file?  Right-click on it and copy the link address or link location.
6. Go back to editing your weebly page.
7. On the "Elements" tab, go down to "More" and drag in the "Custom HTML" element.
8. Click to edit the custom HTML element-  this is where we are going to put our applet code.
9. If my link location to my .class file was http://www.johndoe.com/uploads/3/3/2/6/3326331/countme.class, my applet code would read:

   `<applet codebase="http://www.johndoe.com/uploads/3/3/2/6/3326331" code="countme.class" width=something height=something></applet>`

The idea is that the codebase tells the browser where to look for a .class file and the code itself tells it whick .class it is.
10.  Publish again, and your applet should appear.

I haven't tried it personally, but I had a chat with a support support staff and they affirmed this method.

All the best!